# What is Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets and what is it used for?

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2022

I was in hot pursuit of a big mystery in a Visual Studio 2022 C# testing project that I didn't originally create.  I couldn't figure out how a certain EXE in a folder was making its way into the bin folder when I did a build.  This EXE was not being produced by the build, but was part of an external tool that happened to be in a Lib folder within the solution folder.  I had removed a reference to this EXE from the csproj file and thought everything was good to go to prevent it from being copied to bin.  However, every time I would do a build, that same exe file would still get copied to my bin folder.  I could not figure out for the life of me how this EXE file was getting copied into the bin folder.  There was a DLL that I was using that the EXE also uses, but I didn't think including that DLL in my project would cause the EXE to get copied with it.

Finally I decided to create a dummy file in the bin folder with the same EXE name and make it read-only.  I did the build and suddenly a file-write error occurred in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file.

So, I had found the culprit, but then it raised a question..., What exactly is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets doing?  Is it somehow automatically copying files into the bin folder?  Seems like there is some black magic going on behind the scenes at it is confusing the heck out of me!

Comment: Do have a look at it with a text editor/viewer, it is fairly readable.  Nothing special, just plumbing for msbuild.  `Copy` is one of the default actions it defines, that's how you found it back.  Nothing to do with your problem.  If you want to find out where a file came from then use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" = Detailed.  After a build, copy/paste the content of the Output window into a text editor and search for the file name.

Comment: I've gone through CurrentVersion.targets file.  There are a lot of macro definitions that aren't real obvious as to who sets them and what they get set to.  Putting on detailed logging didn't really reveal anything that shed light on the matter.  Still seems to point to something that CurrentVersion.targets is doing.  I just can't figure out how it is doing it since I have searched the csproj file for any references to the file or the folder in which the file is located and found none.  It is just not there, but yet it is being copied to the bin folder somehow.